# Block .lnk file using virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I want to block access of all txt, lnk, inc files using url.
My virtual host configuration is (last 2 lines):

RewriteEngine on

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*\.lnk
    RewriteRule ^https://mydomain.com$ [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order it like this:

```
RewriteRule .*\.lnk$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

The first line will ensure that any request that ends with `.lnk` will have a 403 forbidden returned. You need it before the other rules because otherwise the `.*` would catch anything containing `.lnk`